# Apache ScriptAlias directory to execute only .php, but server up all others normally

Tags: php, apache

I want to use the same html directory for cgi files. Is there a way to define the ScriptAlias to execute php scripts only but serve all others  as normal html stuff?

my php code executes fine, but other files do not get served up.

Here is the error:

```
[error] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/hosting/content/test-dev/htdocs/users.html' failed
[error Premature end of script headers: users.html
[error] script not found or unable to stat: /hosting/content/test-dev/htdocs/error


    ScriptAlias / "/hosting/content/test-dev/htdocs/"
    <Directory "/hosting/content/test-dev/htdocs/">
....

    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make it a normal `Alias` instead of a `ScriptAlias` and then add:

```
Options +ExecCGI
```

Then it will serve normal content and run executables. But this is not needed for PHP scripts to run. They can go in a normal alias, or document root, and will work fine. `ScriptAlias` or `ExecCGI` is only needed for executables which PHP are not, they just run through a handler that processes the PHP code, which is different.

Comment: In my case, did not need to add Alias. Thanks!